# ngModal not working in md-select in angular 2 material

Tags: angular

Hello I m developing an angular 2 app using material 2. So what I want to do is get data from ng-model into change function of change event, I get data as undefined. Following  is the code.

```
<md-select (change)="trigger(val)" [(ngModel)]="val">
<md-option *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Component:

```
trigger(d){}.//// d is undefined.
```

but if i do this in `<select><option></option></select>`. I do get the data.
Please point me where I m going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using this code

```
<md-select (change)="trigger(newValue.value)" #newValue [(ngModel)]="val">
    <md-option *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>

trigger(value){

}
```

also  why are you passing  `val` value via parameter ,you can easily get this value without passing value like this

```
trigger(){
    console.log(this.val, "ngModal value");
}
```